# How to avoid NaN value in PCA

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, pattern-matching

I used OpenCV PCA to get eigenvectors and eigenvalues. But the eigenVectors are filled with NaN value. So I can't do further process. How to avoid NaN values while PCA in OpenCV?

```
cv::PCA pca(DataBase,cv::Mat(),CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROWS);
```

Comment: Without more information it's difficult to see the exact problem, but I suspect you have a singular covariance matrix. Do you have lots of zeros in your feature vectors?

Comment: No, my input is just vectors of face image  intensities.Its value is about 0 to 255 and totally 80x80 image converted into 1600. 360 images has taken. So totally the input matrix is of 1600x360.